# Convert a columns of string to list in pandas

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, tuples

I have a problem with the type of one of my column in a pandas dataframe. Basically the column is saved in a csv file as a string, and I wanna use it as a tuple to be able to convert it in a list of numbers. Following there is a very simple csv:

```
ID,LABELS
1,"(1.0,2.0,2.0,3.0,3.0,1.0,4.0)"
2,"(1.0,2.0,2.0,3.0,3.0,1.0,4.0)"
```

If a load it with the function "read_csv" I get a list of strings. I have tried to convert to a list, but I get the list version of a string:

```
df.LABELS.apply(lambda x: list(x))
```

returns:

```
['(','1','.','0',.,.,.,.,.,'4','.','0',')']
```

Any idea on how to be able to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`, which will give you a tuple:

```
import ast
df.LABELS = df.LABELS.apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

If you do want a list, use:

```
df.LABELS.apply(lambda s: list(ast.literal_eval(s)))
```

Answer (score 35):

Use [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df['LABELS'] = df['LABELS'].str.strip('()').str.split(',')
```

But if no `NaN`s here, `list comprehension` working nice too:

```
df['LABELS'] = [x.strip('()').split(',') for x in df['LABELS']]
```

Comment: I will say this is the faster solution among 3 :-)

Comment: This yields the warning: `<input>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`.

Comment: Problem is in code above, there is some filtering? Like `df = df[df['col'] > 10]` ?  then need `df = df[df['col'] > 10].copy()` for avoid warning

Comment: If your parameter is already list looking string convert `()` to `[]`.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I was late to the party. So for other latecomers I got this to work based on the above replies:

```
df['hashtags'] = df.apply(lambda row:  row['hashtags'].strip('[]').replace('"', '').replace(' ', '').split(',')   , axis=1)
```

I loaded a csv with some columns looking like this ...,['hashtag1','hashtag2'],... and the Panda DataFrame loaded it as a string object. I used the above code and it converted to list. I then used "explode" to flatten the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this (assuming your `csv` is called `filename.csv`):

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

df['LABELS'] = df.LABELS.apply(lambda x: x.strip('()').split(','))

>>> df
   ID                               LABELS
0   1  [1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 4.0]
1   2  [1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 4.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you might consider regular expressions:

```
pattern = re.compile("[0-9]\.[0-9]")
df.LABELS.apply(pattern.findall)
```