# Find globally unique elements from lists within dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column of terms, like:

```py
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(
  ...:     [
  ...:         [123, ["D2334","D7645","D0938","D00001"]],
  ...:         [223, ["A938","D00001","D0938"]],
  ...:         [342, ["B983","D2334"]],
  ...:     ],
  ...:     columns=['ID', 'terms'],
  ...: ).set_index('ID')

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
                             terms
ID
123  [D2334, D7645, D0938, D00001]
223          [A938, D00001, D0938]
342                  [B983, D2334]
```

I want to get for each ID a list of terms which are globally unique, i.e :

```py
ID       terms
123  ["D7645"]
223   ["A938"]
342   ["B983"]
```

for example , i want to delete "D2334" because it exist in two or many IDs ...

Comment: See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).  You need to "melt" or "explode" your rows, and then find unique elements.  Each of these is a straightforward lookup.

Comment: Hi - welcome to stack overflow! @Prune did suggest some good things to check for. Generally they are pointing to the fact that Pandas isn't really designed for handling lists within dataframes, so using [`pd.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) may be helpful. This could explode your memory too, though.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado user has changed df creation but, noticed that sometimes list are read as strings depending of which way you import them...

Answer (score 0):

You can collapse all list elements to a single numpy array by stacking the values:

```py
all_terms = np.hstack(df.terms.values)
```

then you can use numpy's unique to find all unique terms, as well as their frequency, and limit to only unique terms which appear once:

```py
unique, counts = np.unique(all_terms, return_counts=True)
unique_with_only_one_appearance = unique[counts == 1]
```

Finally, it sounds like you're trying to filter the terms to only include these unique terms:

```py
df['unique_terms'] = df.terms.apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i in unique_with_only_one_appearance])
```

This isn't a terribly efficient workflow, and there may be better ways of organizing your data if you are working with large sets of tokens besides pandas. You could always check out the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange site for tips on tools to use for a dataset like this.

Answer (score 0):

In case you import from a csv for instance, you may have an str type instead of your list:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

test_df = pd.read_csv('test_df.csv', sep=';')

if isinstance(test_df.iloc[0]['terms'], str): # check type of record terms 
    print(type(test_df.iloc[0]['terms']))
    test_df['terms'] = test_df['terms'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

test_df = test_df.explode('terms', ignore_index=True)
test_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['terms', ], keep=False, inplace=True)


print(test_df)
```

output:

```
<class 'str'>
    ID  terms
1  123  D7645
4  223   A938
7  342   B983
```

Not exactly your output but my guess is that you may prefer, having the terms as str rather than between brackets.

ref:

[cast str to tuple/list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278300/convert-a-columns-of-string-to-list-in-pandas)

[pd.explode doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)