# Extract list from pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a excel spreadsheet that has a table like this:

| Variable | bins_edges_list |
| --- | --- |
| var1 | [0.998, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 10.0, 14.0, 90.0] |
| var2 | [0.999, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 9.0, 11.0, 14.0, 90.0] |
| var3 | [-0.001, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 7.0, 83.0] |

I read it into a pandas dataframe using the command

```
df_bin_edges = pd.read_excel('bin_edges_data_backup.xlsx')
df_bin_edges = df_bin_edges[['Variable','bins_edges_list']]
```

I tried to extract the bins corresponding to "Variable"

```
bins_list = df_bin_edges[df_bin_edges['Variable'] == 'var1']['bins_edges_list']
bins_list.replace("'","")
```

What I expect to see is

```
bins_list = [0.998, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 10.0, 14.0, 90.0]
```

but I get the following instead

```
bins_list = '[0.998, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 10.0, 14.0, 90.0]'
```

I want to use this bins_list in pd.cut to divide variables into bins.

```
pd.cut(df[col], bins=bins_list,labels=None, retbins=False, duplicates='drop', precision=0).astype(str)
```

I get the following error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[0.998, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 10.0, 14.0, 90.0]'
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278300/convert-a-columns-of-string-to-list-in-pandas

Comment: You may have to specify the dtype argument to read_excel, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591466/python-pandas-how-to-specify-data-types-when-reading-an-excel-file

Answer (score 0):

It's because reading it doesn't automatically make it a `list`, so try using `pd.eval`.

Add the following line after this line `df_bin_edges = df_bin_edges[['Variable','bins_edges_list']]`:

```
df['bins_edges_list'] = df['bins_edges_list'].apply(pd.eval)
```

Comment: Thanks, but pd.eval didnt help.

Comment: @Zenvega Edited my answer and should work now!

Comment: @Zenvega Please try the new code

Comment: @Zenvega Di you try it yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try via `literal_eval()`:

```
from ast import literal_eval:

df['bins_edges_list']=df['bins_edges_list'].map(literal_eval)
```

OR

via `pd.eval()`

```
df['bins_edges_list']=pd.eval(df['bins_edges_list'])
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) would help.

The problem is that `['bins_edges_list']` is a column containing string, you need to split the characters and for each character create a new column for the Dataframe.